# Using a static iOS library with RubyMotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, rubymotion

I am interested in RubyMotion, but would like to understand more about using 3rd party iOS frameworks before paying the license fee.

I see in section 2.2 [here](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/), it states:

> "To vendor a 3rd-party library in a RubyMotion project, the source
>   code must be available somewhere on the filesystem."

My understanding of an iOS framework is essentially a static library (.a file) and a bunch of header files, with **no** source code - this seems to suggest to me that it is not possible to use a 3rd party iOS framework with RubyMotion.

However, reading this documentation further states that it is possible to supply the project type `:static` to the `vendor_project` method along with `:products` (an array of static library names) and `:headers_dir` (path to the directory that contains public headers files). This seems to contradict the assertion that the source code must be available.

So my question  - is it possible to use a closed-source 3rd party iOS framework with RubyMotion where there is no access to the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's totally possible. I think what the documentation means is just you need to include everything you use in the project.

You can either use a xcode project or as you said, a static library(.a file) with several header files (maybe some objective-c wrapper files too).

something like this in your Rakefile will do the job!

```
app.vendor_project('vendor/your-lib-name', :static,
    :products => ['lib.a'],
    :headers_dir => 'lib-header-path')
```

here is [an article](http://markvillacampa.com/2012/06/09/how-to-use-objective-c-libraries-with-rubymotion/) that I found really helpful, it explains well how to use 3rd party library in RubyMotion.

Other than including a library in your project manually, you can also use libraries available on Cocoapods. There is a RubyMotion wrapper - motioncocoapods for this, i recently done [an article](http://www.moodstocks.com/2013/01/28/the-moodstocks-real-time-image-recognition-sdk-now-available-as-a-pod-on-cocoapods/) on this subject, you can have a look if you are interestd.